# SharePoint Online App Registration is failing

Tags: rest, sharepoint, oauth-2.0

Goal: Register a custom App so that I can use the ClientId and ClientSecret for AppOnly OAuth2 Rest calls to my SharePoint Online site/s.

About a month ago I was able to go to the AppRegNew.aspx page, and register an app.  This gave me everything I needed, and you could see the registered App in AppPrincipals.aspx.  However, now when I go through the process the form submits, but the app is not registered.  You cannot view the app in the AppPrincipals.aspx page.

I then tried various other methods to register a custom App including creating a SharePoint App project, and uploading it to a Catalog site I created within my Site Collection.  Here it registers the App, displays in the AppPrincipals.aspx page, but does not allow authentication.  Deploying (Right Click the project, hit "Deploy") the App from Visual Studio to a Development themed Site has a similar result.

The only way I have had success is by building a SharePoint App, and hitting debug from Visual Studio.  I can transfer the Client ID and Client Secret to my web app that I deploy in Azure, and it works.

What has changed!?! I am assuming this is a bug, and has been introduced recently.  There is so much documentation from Microsoft that says this is the best practice and expected way to connect with SharePoint 2013, SharePoint Online, Office 365, etc that I truly have to believe this is a bug.

http://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx

Comment: This is affecting me here as well since SharePoint 2013 Workflows are dependent on AppReg as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499786/sharepoint-online-2013-workflows-not-completing

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is fixed now.

Old:

Yes, I'm getting a 500 error too. Looks like a bug on their side. Probably better to report this on MS/SharePoint forums, so I added it [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/d7ca59f2-74c0-431e-b431-ce55eaa6569a/appregnew-appprincipals-doesnt-work-anymore?forum=onlineservicessharepoint).

Comment: Thank you.  Looking forward to seeing any results here.  My first post was here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f6ec0d4c-8051-4e3c-8050-3fd4fe841e6d/registering-an-app-is-failing-to-properly-set-clientid-and-clientsecret-for-apponly-oauth2?forum=appsforsharepoint